How to use the "Save screen shot" feature of Wayback Machine in Internet Archive?
When you visit https://web.archive.org/save to save a webpage, there is a checkbox that says "Save screen shot". I imagined that this checkbox would make the Wayback Machine create a .png image of the page in addition to archiving it. However, I didn't manage to find this .png image for archives I've created. So, does it actually create a .png, and if yes, how to I access it?


Save Example
To save (aka archive/snapshot) a page along with a screenshot at web.archive.org/save:

Save detailsPage:   https://webapps.stackexchange.com
Date:   Aug. 1,2024
Time:   10:22:48 EDT (UTC-4) 
☑/true: Save screen shot

Save result:A snapshot was captured. Visit page:
https://web.archive.org/web/20240801142248/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/
A screen shot was captured. View screen shot:
https://web.archive.org/web/20240801142248/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/


Access screenshot
If a screenshot exists for a snapshot you can access it using one of the following approaches:
From Snapshot URL

Take an existing snapshot URL such as  the one generated above:https://web.archive.org/web/20240801142248/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Break it into its component parts:page_url: https://webapps.stackexchange.com
datetime: 20240801142248 (UTC) 
base_url: web.archive.org/web

The screenshot portion of the path will be:screenshot_path: http://web.archive.org/screenshot

The URL syntax for the snapshot's screenshot if it exists would be:https://[base_url]/[datetime]/[screenshot_path]/[page_url]


From the GUI

As Ciro Santilli wrote in their answer there's a screenshot button  on the right side of the app toolbar when viewing a snapshot.
It's worth noting that when accessing the snapshot from Chrome Mobile the screenshot button  was only displayed when the screen was oriented in landscape mode but missing in portrait mode along with several other buttons       

Chrome mobile browser (Android):
Landscape Orientation

Portrait Orientation





Thanks for this. So there seems to be no way via GUI after the result page is that closed is that correct? You just have to know how to modify the URL.

Ah, I found the button. I'll mention in a separate answer.

There's a button on the top bar with a little camera if the archive has a snapshot which leads to the snapshot page e.g. at https://web.archive.org/web/20240801142248/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ there is a link to: https://web.archive.org/web/20240801142256/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

